# Ajax.beginform does a full postback

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am using Ajax,beginform to get partial postback, have install the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax package, set up the bundle and added the keys in config files. With all this done when i click my submit button i get full postback. Have gone though tones of post and tried all suggested solutions, still seems to not work. is there anything i am still missing.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions()
 {
       HttpMethod = "GET",
       UpdateTargetId = "divList",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
  }))
  {
       <button type="submit"><span><span class="sr-only">Show more List</span></span></button>
  }
 <div id="divList">
     @Html.Partial("_MyList.cshtml", Model.List)
 </div>
```

In my controller

```
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        .....
        return PartialView("_MyList", list);
    }
```

Added in the bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                          "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                          "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

In web.config

```
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Have even tried setting the section script in my view

```
@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: If you doing a redirect, then it means `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loaded. Check for any errors in the browser console. Also check that you do not have any duplicate scripts (e.g. loading `jquery-{version}.js` again after `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`)

Comment: @Stephen, I do not get any error on the console, i even registered jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js directly and made sure jquery duplicated. still it does not work.

Comment: Its definitely an issue with the scripts if its redirecting. But `Ajax.BeginForm()` is awful and has been dropped in the latest MVC so better to use the jquery ajax methods anyway. - `<button type="button" id="show">Show more List</button>` and `$('#show").click(function() { $('#divList').load('@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'); })`

Answer (score 0):

Another best way to handle the scenario is, instead of **Ajax.BeginForm** use **Html.BeginForm**

Use JQuery form submit, this will help you to stay away from **jquery.unobtrusive**

**In .cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_" + @Model.Id }))
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AntiForgeryToken, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })

            <button onclick='onClickFormButton("form_@Model.Id")' type="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onClickFormButton = function (formId) {
    //validate the form clientside
    var validateResult = OnValidateForm(formId);
    if (!validateResult) return false;

    var form = $('#' + formId);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            // process the result
            processSuccessResult(result)
        },
        fail: function (result) {
            // process the result
            processFailResult(result)
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**Controller/Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ActionName(FormCollection model)
{
    // Get  id
    var idKey = model.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("Id"));
    var id = model[idKey];
    
    return new ProcessedResult(id);
}
```